# How can I make my Player jump when I press a UI button? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a bit of a issue on one of my projects. So I'm trying to make my character jump when I press a UI button, but I haven't been able to make it work thus far. I tried adding a Rigidbody to my Player and just doing:

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public void onJumpButton()
{
rb.AddForce(Vector3.up* jumpForce);
}
```

and this is on my buttons On Click () function but that didn't work. 
I already have jumping figured out on the pc and for pc my code is:

```
   if (controller.isGrounded)
    {

        verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {

            verticalVelocity = jumpForce;
            animator.SetBool("is_in_air", true);
            jump.Play();


        }

    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("is_in_air", false);
        verticalVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

and this works fine when i press space on PC but I need to incorporate this into a UI button for Cellphone use. If anyone has any tips on how I can do this that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Rigidbody can not work with CharacterController

Comment: Yes I noticed that, I removed the rigidbody and that piece of code after trying it and seeing that it didnt work.

Comment: If you remove the rigidbody then what's in `onJumpButton` method?

Comment: Well right now it woulld be nothing. That is what I need help with, I can't figure out how to make it jump when pressing the button since the Rigidbody didn't work. The jump method I have for Space works fine, but I don't know how to make that work in the `onJumpButton`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the same function if it works ? Move all your jumping code in a function, then call that function on user input and in the OnClick() of your button

Comment: I tried using the same code in the function and the OnClick() of my button but it did not work the same way, my Player just ends upp jumping constantly in a loop.